# Facing below aligning my input and buttons at the bottom center of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have tried to use justify content but the content contiously stacks on top of the other
below is my code and why i have tried

```
                          input

                          button

                          input

                          input

                          button
```

Above is how i would like the layout to look
I tried implementing classes for each and every input but coudnt make the not stack on top of each other any help would be greatly aprreciated.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit_address"]))
    {
        $address = $_POST["address"];
        $address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
        ?>
 
        <iframe padding ="5px" width="100%" margin="5px"  height="600px" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $address; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
 
        <?php
    }

  if (isset($_POST["submit_coordinates"]))
    {
        $latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
        $longitude = $_POST["longitude"];
        ?>
 
        <iframe padding ="5px" width="100%" margin="5px"  height="600px" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
 
        <?php
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Livestock Dashboard</title>
    <style>
        button{
            width: 7%;
    height: 45px;
    background: #2364d2;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 20px 0px rgba(35, 100, 210, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;


   
        }

        input{
            text-align: center;
            width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid #ced6e0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: none;
    color: #1a3b5d;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;




        }

        body {
  background-image: url('bull.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

        </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter address">
    </p>
 
<div style="justify-content:left; align-items:center; display:flex;">
<button type="submit" name="submit_address" style ="
    ">
    Submit
</button>
</div>
</form>
<form method="POST">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="latitude" placeholder="Enter latitude">
    </p>
 
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="longitude" placeholder="Enter longitude">
    </p>
 
  <div style="justify-content:left; align-items:center; display:flex;">
  <button type="submit" name="submit_coordinates">
    Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using justify content on the div but id didnt work

Comment: Can you do a minimal reproduction : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The English is quite difficult to understand but hopefully this will help you.

Add the following to the style in your `<form>`:

```
style="display: flex;  justify-content: stretch;"
```

Change the justify-content and center as fit. An easy to understand list of possible options you can use can be found [here](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/justify-content-examples), or you can use a better documented [list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) from Mozilla.

This will make make your inputs and submit button be next to each other rather than stacked.

A mock on CodePen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/NathanPortelli/pen/poZPBjL?editors=1010).

Also, remove the `width: 7%;` from your button's style.

[image: "result"]